# Query for enabled categories

Tags: templating, categories, query

In a template, I want to show only enabled categories. I can't figure out how to filter the returned categories by only enabled ones, without doing it in the `for` loop.

This works:

```
{% for category in craft.categories.level(1) if category.enabled %}
  # only enabled categories
{% endfor %}
```

but instantiates the disabled categories, even though they won't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
% for category in craft.categories.level(1).enabled(true) %}
    # only enabled categories
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Couldn't find anything in the docs about this and thought I was losing my mind